# Android java support for FIFO data transfer between bound Service and Activity?

Tags: android, binding, fifo

I'm all excited about binding an activity to a Service and transferring data without using a handler. Namely, I would like to use a FIFO for continually transferring streaming data from my Service to one of my Activities on an event driven basis. This is all within one application.

I must have been absent that day in Java 101. But since then I think I have read about support for FIFO's between a Service and Activity. I got the "bound thing" just a hummin'. But I can't figure out how to transfer the data reliably between a Service and an Activity. So I think I need a FIFO - really good one. It can be built-in, built-on, or from a third party.

What I was expecting to find was event driven support. You know, the Service has data and instead of busy waiting, do something like synchronization, and non-blocking transfers from the Service to the Activity while I'm at it Do I have a critical section here or what? This just seems like such a classic problem with a classic solution.

Pardon me I have lost my glasses, but my son did proof read this. Thanks for any help.

Please help.

Comment: It must be easier than I think it is. Construct a FIFO queque in my LocalService then write two sets of methods. One will be for the LocalService to write to my FIFO. The other set of methods will be defined in my LocalBinder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what ended up working:
1. Binding to the service
2. Passing it a handler